# cpp linked list program:error in display

Tags: c++, oop

following is my simple doubly linked list program to insert a node and display the linked list,

i am getting an error in displaying the linked list,

the problem in the program is even if i add several new nodes,when i select to display the stored linked list it is showing the list is empty,
since i am a newbie i am unable to locate the logical error,please help me out,

the code is as follows

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class DLL;
class node

{
    int data;
    class node *next;
    class node *prev;
    friend class DLL;
    node(int x)
    {
        data=x;
        next=NULL;
        prev=NULL;
    }

};

class DLL
{
    node *start;
public:     DLL();
            void insert();
            void display();
};

DLL::DLL()
{
    start=NULL;
}

void DLL::insert()
{
    class node *p;
    int no;
    cout<<"enter number";
    cin>>no;
    p=new node(no);
    if(start==NULL)
    {
        p->next=NULL;
        p->prev=NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        p->next=start;
        p->prev=NULL;
        p->next->prev=p;
        start=p;
    }
}

void DLL::display()
{
    node *temp;
    temp=start;
    if(temp==NULL)
    {
        cout<<"list is empty\n";
    }
    else
    {
        while(temp!=NULL)
        {
            cout<<temp->data<<"\t";
            temp=temp->next;
        }

    }
}

int main()
{
    DLL d1;
    int ch=1;
    while(ch!=3)
    {
        cout<<"enter choice\n1 to insert\n2 to display\n";
        cin>>ch;
        switch(ch)
        {
        case 1:d1.insert();break;
        case 2:d1.display();break;
        default:cout<<"wrong input\n";break;
        }
    }

}
```

---

While reviewing my questions of stackoverflow i found this question
and realized what difficulties beginners might face and hence im adding the solution to mistake made by me

the logical error was in 'insert' function, i was not assigning node to start and hence it was showing empty linked list

the solution to it can be as following

```
void DLL::insert()
{
    class node *p;
    int no;
    cout<<"enter number";
    cin>>no;
    p=new node(no);
    if(start==NULL)
    {
        p->next=NULL;
        p->prev=NULL;
        start = p; //this step needs to be added so that start will be assigned a node and not be null
    }
    else
    {
        p->next=start;
        p->prev=NULL;
        p->next->prev=p;
        start=p;
    }
}
```

thanks for @WhozCraig to his answer!

Comment: Certainly I can help: learn how to use a debugger before you write a another single line of code.

Comment: You never assign `start = p` in the case when your linked list is empty (i.e. first insertion). The list stays empty and you leak the node you just allocated. Move `start=p;` **out** of the else block below that so it unconditionally executes for both `if` and `else` cases. (i.e. move it after the closing `}` of the else block).

Comment: Maybe I'm just a neat-freak, but why are people okay with leaving their code completely unformatted and scattered like this?

Comment: @WhozCraig which was almost predictable. (LL corner cases), and I couldn't be bothered looking:)

Comment: @MartinJames its why I do these with pointers-to-pointers (and I don't do them at all in C++, using the standard library instead, as I'm sure you do too).

Comment: What annoys is that the most trivial attempt at debugging would have revealed the problem.  Even newbs should be able to printf/cout some useful values to find the bug.

Comment: `since i am a newbie i am unable to locate the logical error,`  However, you wrote the program.  Anytime you have the knowledge to write a program, it is a given that you know how to debug the program you wrote.  Otherwise, what you're saying is that you're throwing random lines of C++ at the compiler, and not knowing what you're doing.

Comment: like i said im a newbie,
thank you for you suggestions, i will learn how to use a debugger and start using it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never assign an initial node. This is the kind of problem that a sheet of paper, a pencil, and two minutes of drawing arrows and boxes should solve, and until you're **fluent** in dynamic allocation get used to doing a *lot* of that.

This:

```
if(start==NULL)
{
    p->next=NULL;
    p->prev=NULL;
    // NOTE: start is still NULL
}
else
{
    p->next=start;
    p->prev=NULL;
    p->next->prev=p;
    start=p;
}
```

should be this:

```
if(start==NULL)
{
    p->next=NULL;
    p->prev=NULL;
}
else
{
    p->next=start;
    p->prev=NULL;
    p->next->prev=p;
}
start=p; // NOTE: start always references the last node allocated.
```

But it is worth noting that the constructor for `node` already sets your member pointers `next` and `prev` to `NULL`. Therefore the above code is further reducible to simply :

```
if (start != NULL)
{
    p->next=start;
    start->prev=p;
}
start=p;
```

---

That said, the real solution is `std::list<int>` or `std:vector<int>`, but I suppose you have to start somewhere. Best of luck.

Comment: +1, and I think pencil and paper are the most underrated development tools.